# Custom Hit Detection on Konva Group

Tags: konvajs

I'm attempting to expand the click area of a group of shapes, but there appears to be no hitFunc property on groups.

```
  var patternControl = new Konva.Group();
  patternControl.hitFunc(function(context) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(0, 0, outerRadius + patternWidth, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    });
```

Is there any way to do apply custom hit functions to a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only shapes can be used for hit detection. As a workaround, you can disable hits for all shapes with `shape.listeting(false)` and then add a "fake" shape to the group that will be used as a hit area:

```
var patternControl = new Konva.Group();
var hitShape = new Konva.Shape({
  // make it transparent, so it is not visible
  fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  hitFunc: (context, shape) => {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(0, 0, outerRadius + patternWidth, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
  }
});
patternControl.add(hitShape);
```

Comment: This should be a viable approach. You can of course make the hit-detecting shape transparent so that it still receives hits but does not appear visible to the user.